# Ada95 Tagged Limited Record giving me error "Completion of nonlimited type cannot be limited"

Tags: compiler-errors, record, ada

I have a generic binary search tree package, called gen_BST and its' child that I just created called gen_BST.AVL.

When I try compiling my code, the Ada compiler gives me an error message saying:
"completion of nonlimited type cannot be limited" -- What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Ignoring the body/specification, this is the record declarations:

```
--Gen_BST:
--Type Declarations
   TYPE Node IS LIMITED PRIVATE; -- The node itself.
   TYPE Root IS ACCESS Node;     -- Pointer to the node.

PRIVATE

--Record Declaration
   TYPE Node IS TAGGED LIMITED RECORD
      Data : Data_Type;
      Left_Child, Right_Child : Root;
   END RECORD;



--Gen_BST.AVL:
   TYPE AVL_Node IS PRIVATE;
   TYPE AVL_Root IS ACCESS AVL_Node;

PRIVATE
   TYPE AVL_Node IS NEW Node WITH RECORD
      Height : Natural;
   END RECORD;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say `type AVL_Node is new Node ...`, `AVL_Node` inherits various properties from `Node`, and one of those properties is limitedness ([ARM 7.5(3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-7-5.html#p3)). The public view of `AVL_Node` is non-limited, so the full view must be too. One fix would be to make the public view limited (`type AVL_Node is limited private;`); alternatively, you could make the full view of `Node` non-limited (`type Node is tagged record ...`).

Many would agree that tagged types should always be limited, but I wonder why `Node` and `AVL_Node` are declared publicly? I'd have thought they were part of the implementation.